# Multiple methods named 'count' found warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, warnings, xcode-workspace

[image]hi, I just updated my dropbox api but i think this shouldn't cause this issuebut after updating i am getting waring in my project when i build it using in xcode 9.2. 
Any idea how to get rid of this warning?

> Multiple methods named 'count' found

Please see the code and attached screenshot for methods calls.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[thumbImagesCollectionArray objectAtIndex:collectionView.tag-1] count];
}
```

Comment: What kind of object do you keep in `thumbImagesCollectionArray`?

Comment: Its  NSMutableArray. actually this is not my code don'tknow much about it. but this warnings i was not getting before untill in updated my dropbox using cartfile update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast `[thumbImagesCollectionArray objectAtIndex:collectionView.tag-1]` to `NSMutableArray` before calling `count`.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    [(NSMutableArray *)[thumbImagesCollectionArray objectAtIndex:collectionView.tag-1] count];
}
```

As I understand, at the compile time, type of object returned when calling `[thumbImagesCollectionArray objectAtIndex:collectionView.tag-1]` isn't known. And it don't know what `count` method should be called on this object. That's why we have warning.

To fix it, cast object returned to `NSMutableArray` so compiler will know what method exactly should be called.

Comment: hi, thanks for the update. yes, this solution works. can you please explain what is the issue here so even others can understand.